# Pandas read_excel reading large integers incorrectly

Tags: python, pandas

I have an xlsx file with a column named `timestamp [us]` having timestamp values in microseconds. The value is displayed in scientific format in the xlsx (as shown in the image). Reading the xlsx file using `pandas.read_excel` results in the timestamp column having a value with a minor difference.

As an example
https://i.stack.imgur.com/guXdO.png

```
xlsx = pd.read_excel("file.xlsx", sheet_name="samples")
print(xlsx["timestamp [us]"][:1]) 

### Output is
 0    1620903125972556
Name: timestamp [us], dtype: int64
###
```

As seen, the value in the dataframe differs from the value in xlsx by 4. I would like help figuring out why this happens and how to retrieve the actual value as in the xlsx.

Comment: I am unable to reproduce the problem. I created a xlsx file with that number seen in the screenshot and read it with pandas. I get it right.

Comment: excel is limited up to 15 digits, - you have 16... rounding applied